# How to increase the size of a detected rectangle for openCV in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I'm using openCV in Python3.6 to detect faces in an image.
It works well enough and detects the face, but I'd like the rectangle to include more of the face (chin, hair, etc.) since those parts are important in recognizing the person. I'm using [this code](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/OpenCV_Python/python_opencv3_Image_Object_Detection_Face_Detection_Haar_Cascade_Classifiers.php).

**How can I get the program to select more of the face?**

Here's an example of what I'm getting (censored for privacy of course)

[image: One of the images]

Comment: Use appropriate face-landmark detection schemes. E.g. the one in [dlib](http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html) (which i also consider more interesting in regards to the available face-processing models and data compared to opencv) which can find points like [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/facial_landmarks_68markup.jpg). When those points have been found it's easy to find the surrounding rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it creates the rectangle, just set a offset/padding

```
padding = 10
cv2.rectangle(img,(x-padding,y-padding),(x+w+padding,y+h+padding),(255,0,0),2)
```

Comment: Is there a content aware way to do it? Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldnt this include part of the background on the right in my example?

Comment: You could detect `facial landmarks` and combine the rectangles to get a bigger `bbox`, but that involves a little more work.  Internally face detect does something similar and padds the rectangle